# okhttp3 how to return value from async GET call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am implementing Helper class in Android studio to service Activity

```
public void getLastId()
{
    //init OkHttpClient
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //backend url
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.1.102:8080/aquabackend/public/customers/lastid")
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            String jsonData = response.body().string();

            try {
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                String id = jobject.getString("id");

                //increment current id +1
                String last_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)+1);
                Log.i("new id", last_id);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Log.i("ok", response.body().string());
        }
    });
```

My function call in activity class

```
Helper helper = new Helper();
helper.getLastId();
//I want to get method to return lastId and then manipulate with the data
```

How can I make method return value of the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is an asynchronous process you won't be able to return a value from the method itself. However, you can use a callback to provide you the value when the asynchronous process has been completed. Below is an example of how you might want to do this.

```
public interface GetLastIdCallback {
    void lastId(String id);
}
```

You would modify getLastId as follows:

```
public void getLastId(GetLastIdCallback idCallback) {
    ...
    String last_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)+1);
    idCallback.lastId(last_id);
    ...

}
```

Your Helper class usage would now look like this:

```
Helper helper = new Helper();
helper.getLastId(new GetLastIdCallback() {
     @Override
     public void lastId(String id) {
         // Do something with your id
     }
});
```

I'd suggest making your callback a bit more generic than I have suggested above. It could look like this:

```
public interface GenericCallback<T> {
    void onValue(T value);
}

...

Helper helper = new Helper();
helper.getLastId(new GenericCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValue(String value) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

If you used an interface like above you would be able to work with any return type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface.

```
public interface Result{
   void getResult(String id);
}
```

Now, pass interface to method as parameter.

```
 Helper helper = new Helper();
      helper.getLastId(new Result(){
        @Override
        void getResult(String id){

        }
});
```

And In your method :

```
public void getLastId(final Result result)
{
    //init OkHttpClient
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //backend url
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.1.102:8080/aquabackend/public/customers/lastid")
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            String jsonData = response.body().string();

            try {
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                String id = jobject.getString("id");

                //increment current id +1
                String last_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)+1);
                Log.i("new id", last_id);
                result.getResult(last_id);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Log.i("ok", response.body().string());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `interface` for it.

```
public interface getResponse {

     void getJsonResponse(final String id);

}
```

In Your code :

```
public void getLastId(fianl getResponse response)
{
    //init OkHttpClient
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //backend url
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.1.102:8080/aquabackend/public/customers/lastid")
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            String jsonData = response.body().string();

            try {
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                String id = jobject.getString("id");

                //increment current id +1
                String last_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)+1);
                Log.i("new id", last_id);
if(response!=null){
response.getJsonResponse(last_id)
}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Log.i("ok", response.body().string());
        }
    });
```

In Activity :

```
 public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Helper helper = new Helper();
      helper.getLastId(new getResponse(){
            @Override
            void getJsonResponse(String id){

            }
    });
}}
    }
```

Comment: Where do I create an interface? In my Helper class?

Comment: It is separate. No need to create in Helper class

Comment: it says Error:(181, 18) error: getJsonResponse(String) in <anonymous com.example.serverexamplecom.demoapp.SendActivity$2> cannot implement getJsonResponse(String) in getResponse
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public