# How to return the result from get (okhttp3)

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I get a result by using okhttp3 get method.
And Now, I want to return the result to MainActivity.

I tried using intent, but I'm failed.
Also I read this [okhttp3 how to return value from async GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237557/okhttp3-how-to-return-value-from-async-get-call). But I confused about where I have to write that code.

```
public interface GetLastIdCallback {
    void lastId(String id);
}
```

my MainActivity:

```
getMaskInfo info = new getMaskInfo(this);
info.requestGet(latitude, longitude);
```

getMaskInfo Activity  (I want to return JSONObject or JSONArray):

```
package com.example.buymaskapp;

public class getMaskInfo {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public static Context mContext;

    public getMaskInfo(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void requestGet(double lat, double lng){
        String url = "https://8oi9s0nnth.apigw.ntruss.com/corona19-masks/v1/storesByGeo/json";

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("lat", Double.toString(lat));
        urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("lng", Double.toString(lng));
        urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("m", "1000");

        String requestUrl = urlBuilder.build().toString();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestUrl).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d("error", "Connect Server Error is " + e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray totalStore = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stores");
                    System.out.println(jsonObject);                          
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `void` from `requestGet()` method, return a `LiveData`

```
public LiveData<JSONObject> requestGet(double lat, double lng) {
   LiveData<JSONObject> result = MutableLiveData<JSONObject>();

   /* reqeust builder & url builder code here */

   client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
   /* override other methods here */

   public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                ((MutableLiveData) result).postValue(jsonObject);                        
            }catch (JSONException e){
                /* catch and do something */
            }
        }
   });

   return result;
}
```

Observe the livedata in mainactivity

```
info.requestGet(latitude, longitude).observe(getViewLifeCycleOwner, new Observer() {
   @Override
   public void onCanged(JSONObject result) {
       /* code to use result */   
   }
});
```

Otherwise, you can also implement interface on mainactivity and use its instance in getMaskInfo or in requestGet method to send back data.

Comment: I tried. but I have a problem in `result.postValue(jsonObject);`. Error is that: Variable 'result' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. So I modified code. Then I had a other problem: 'postValue' has protected access in 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData'. How can fix this problem?

Comment: Since we have declared `result` as `LiveData` object where `postValue()` is restricted; type cast it to `MutableLiveData` object where `postValue()` is not restricted.

Comment: I solved it with another way. But really really thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a callback in MainActivity:
`public void onResult(JSONArray stores)` 
or whatever you want to return from the call. Since you now know that your `mContext`  is actually `MainActivity`, you can make a cast and call that method
`((MainActivity)mContext).onResult(totalStore)`.

If you need to use `getMaskInfo` with other activities as well, you can put method `onResult` into an interface, make `MainActivity` implement that interface and pass the interface as an argument to `getMaskInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

> Interface class

```
public interface GetLastIdCallback {
    void lastId(String id);
    void getJSONCallback(JSONObject  object);
}
```

> Update the onResponse function

```
 @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray totalStore = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stores");
                    System.out.println(jsonObject); 
                    ((GetLastIdCallback )(mContext)).getJSONCallback(jsonObject);   //Return here                     
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });
```

> Calling activity must implement GetLastIdCallback interface

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GetLastIdCallback{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    @Override
    public void lastId(String id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void getJSONCallback(JSONObject object) {
        //Here you can use response according to your requirements 

    }
}
```